# Return to default after e.preventDefault()

Tags: jquery

When a user loads a page I disable scroll on mobile, so the page remains fixed, as follows:

```
 $(document).on('touchmove', function(e) { e.preventDefault(); });
```

But how can I reactivate scroll again with JQuery, in other words go back to the default.

Thanks!

Comment: Just turn off that event by, `$(document).off('touchmove')`